# ArrayFormula & Vlookup: exclude the current row from Vlookup range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a simple booking system using GoogleSheets.
Each entry (Row) is a "booking request".
The intervals being entered on the sheet (via a form) are fixed to 1, 2 or 3 hours (which makes this a "simple booking system"). I'm validating these "booking requests" based on "overlaps" in Start & End Time in a couple separate columns L, M, N.

[Sheet Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZ0v.png)

**The Formula**

```
      IF(ROW($A:$A)=1,
            "CheckEndDateTimes (1 hour after Start)",
            IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($E1:$E+1/24,$G$2:$G,1,FALSE)),
               "",
               "overlaps 1 hour ahead of start"
           )
        )
     )
```

I'm using ArrayFormula, such that it auto-updates Sheet data as entries are added via a form. I'm using VLOOKUP because it seems to work well with ArrayFormula (as opposed to Index/Match).

**The generalized issue:**

- Column E contains the search_key values (i.e. $E1:$E) (Start Datetime).
- Column G contains the range (i.e. $G:$G) (End Datetimes), which I am using to compare intervals (1, 2, 3 hours) ADDED to the search_key value (Column E)
- SO far this works fine, EXCEPT that the Row that is being evaluated ALWAYS evaluates to an overlap; clearly, the mere existence of the End Time in the Row being evaluated is always resulting in an overlap.

**My Question**
Is there a way I can EXCLUDE the current row from the range being evaluated in the VLOOKUP function. (I tried adding "<>", as follows, but it results in NO matches being found:

```
VLOOKUP($E1:$E+1/24,$G$2:$G<>$G1:$G,1,FALSE)
```

Or even (to test),
   `VLOOKUP($E1:$E+1/24,$G$2:$G<>$G$4,1,FALSE)`

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you kindly. :)

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! 
Here's a sample GoogleSheet file: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L3yk7sUI6mYlxiswBqI_K4ORag3mShFymYQA5JFIdGw/edit#gid=0

Quick note, it references different columns than specified above. 

In Columns H to J, I've illustrated the desired output from the formula.

To clarify: for each "booking request", I am trying to identify if there's another "End Time" that exists 1 hour after "Start Time" (same with 2 hours and 3 hours).

In a subsequent step, I will combine these 3 results to verify if the booking can be confirmed or not. Thanks again!

Comment: Please review your tags, it doesn't seem that it is related to excel. Thanks

Comment: would you clarify what is your overlap condition for a given end date row? it seems you are looking for the entire range for looking for overlap (`VLOOKUP`). It doesn't have to be expressed on Google Sheet terms, just in simple words. Thanks

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Maybe use countif instead of vlookup and see if the result is more than one?

Comment: @David - thank you so much for your time with this.
My use of VLOOKUP on the entire End Datetime range (Col C) is to check each entry's Start Datetime +1 hour (and +2 and +3 hours) against ALL End entries. 
The idea is that, depending on a given entry's Duration (col B), I would check columns D,E,F. If the correct ones are blank, then the entry is Valid (i.e. "Booking Request is accepted"). Else, there's an overlap and Booking request is "denied".
Quick note, my form only accepts a full hour (i.e. 16:00, 17:00, etc), and max 3 hours per booking. This is why I consider this method may work.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the suggestion - yes, COUNTIF may also work, but I'm having issues with it as well... I may have to start a new Question, but when I put COUNTIF() inside ARRAYFORMULA(), it does not return expected result. 
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($C$2:$C3,">="&($A4:A)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On reflection I think you need to use countifs to check for any rows with a matching overlapped time and with a row number not equal to the current row like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,countifs(C2:C,A2:A+1/24,row(C2:C),"<>"&row(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Then you can test whether the result is non-zero and display a message:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,if(countifs(C2:C,A2:A+1/24,row(C2:C),"<>"&row(A2:A)),"overlaps 1 hour",)))
```

and similarly for 2 and 3 hours.

BTW I don't think row three does overlap at one hour.

Comment: Thank you very much to you and everyone else that assisted me with this issue.

Indeed, COUNTIF was the way to go, and in fact, the solution turned out to apply regardless of "Booking duration". Here is the final formula that I ended up using:

=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",COUNTIFS($C$2:$C,">="&$A2:$A,$A$2:$A,"<="&$C2:$C)))

Comment: Once I actually got this step to work (identifying overlaps), the next (and final) step was to "Approve only the first Booking Request that overlaps others" (in a FIFO manner). The following article helped a lot, in case it helps anyone else: 

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/79817164/trying-to-sequentially-number-instances-of-duplicate-entries-1st-2nd-3rd-etc?hl=en

Finally, my little project is now complete and is working as intended. Thank you all once again!